# How to profile in the Linux kernel or use the perf_event*.[hc] framework?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, arm, profiling

I have noticed there are some profiling source code under arch/arm/kernel:

```
perf_event.c 
perf_event_cpu.c 
perf_event_v6.c 
perf_event_v7.c 
perf_event_xscale.c
```

I can't understand the hierarchy of those files and how can I use them? can I assume they are always exists and use them in a kernel module? my kernel module runs on Cortex-A7 or Cortex-A15 cores.

There seems to be a lot of very useful things under `/arch/arm/kernel/` directory but no documentation about the capabilities ? how comes ?

Comment: Can you instead use the `perf` userspace tool which is popular on x86-style targets?  Or do you actually need access to perfcounters from the kernel?

Comment: I need both, I have one user space application on Android platform and a kernel module I write which I can't use perf with it.

Comment: What does it mean that you can't "use perf with it"?  The code in your module will get sampled when it executes.  Do you need this feature you describe as a development tool occasionally or do you intend that your module should be able to interact with the perfcounters as a part of its normal operation?

Comment: I issue I have 3 projects one is a kernel module and userland app I can compile with `-g` flag and perf will be able to sample it (not sure how to do it exactly but I know it is feasible), second thing I have a bare metal code which I need to use by myself the performance counters.
the third one is to interact with the PMU within a dedicated kernel module.

Comment: **perf_event_v7.c** is for the Cortex series afaik.  The **perf_event.c** and **perf_event_cpu.c** are probably infra-structure things.  The other two files are for different CPUs (ARM11, XScale).  Maybe you guessed that already?  The ARMV7 manual has information in a chapter about the registers.  I think you need this for your *bare metal* part.

Comment: @artlessnoise any chance you format your comments and notes into an answer ?

Comment: I am guessing what you want.  Mats already did a good job of answering the question as it stands.  Try to search SO for [arm+pmu](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+pmu).  There are good hits.  Work through it and find some registers that you need more of a comment on.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247373/how-to-measure-program-execution-time-in-arm-cortex-a8-processor) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795132/measure-executing-time-on-arm-cortex-a8-using-hardware-counter) also look helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality in the `perf_*` files is used by/provided for tools like `oprofile` and `perf` tools.

And no, they are not ALWAYS available, as there is a config option (CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS) to enable/disable performance measurements.

The functionality is not really meant to be used from another driver. I'm pretty sure that will "upset" any user of `oprofile` or `perf`.

Comment: See my reply to your above comment: in short, the functionality in the perf_* files is accessible through the perf_event API, which is available in user- and kernel-space, and the oprofile and perf tools are user-space programs, so won't help the OP do performance measurements in a module.

Answer (score 4):

Perf_event does provide an API that can be used programmatically, but the documentation is sparse at best. Vince Weaver made the best resource for using the perf_event API here: http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/

He also provides some example code for recording counters.

However your best bet is to use an API that wraps perf_event and makes it more accessible, like PAPI (http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/)

EDIT: Since you want to do this from a kernel module, PAPI will not be available. The perf_event API still is, however.

Comment: Am I missing something, or dose PAPI only work in user-mode? The original question is, at least partly "how to use this in a kernel driver". I think it is rather harsh to downvote my answer and then give a new answer that doesn't actually answer the original question. It's a free country, so you are alloowed to downvote my answer, but to have the courtesy to give a comment as to WHAT is wrong wouldn't go amiss. Also, providing an answer that actually covers the original question completely would probably be appreciated (even if it's a year and  half after the question was originally asked)

Comment: I downvoted because you said perf_events is not meant to be used by a driver, when it in fact does provide an API, one that is accessible from both kernel-space and user-space. You're right that PAPI is user-space, so maybe that point was irrelevant given that the OP wants to use this in a kernel driver, and also I apologize for not previously justifying the downvote. Is there any reason why using the perf_event API isn't a complete answer to the question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dislike downvotes on old answers with no comment, because it doesn't teach the person writing the answer anything, and if I'm wrong, I want to know what I'm wrong about (and sometimes I have a feeling people downvote for no particular reason!)