# How to count the number of instructions executed in an ARM program?

Tags: linux, performance, assembly, linux-kernel, arm

I want to perform performance measurement of a change I want to make to an application by counting instructions. However, I'm not familiar enough with ARM's debug interface to know how to do this. Is there even an interface for this sort of thing? I'm perfectly capable of diving into the kernel if necessary, but my intuition tells me this sort of thing ought to be implemented in userspace.

Comment: Take a look at this discussion of accessing the cycle counters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247373/how-to-measure-program-execution-time-in-arm-cortex-a8-processor

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm running in a simulator, which renders cycle counts useless. I have to rely on instruction counts instead.

Comment: Which simulator are you using? Maybe it has the ability to report instruction counts, or to produce an instruction trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS` in Linux kernel `.config`

Userspace tools for accessing this are in `linux-source/tools/perf/`

`HW_PERF_EVENTS` enables PMU, `CPU_HAS_PMU` is defined thusly: `(CPU_V6 || CPU_V6K || CPU_V7 || XSCALE_PMU) && (!ARCH_OMAP3 || OMAP3_EMU)` so your chip likely has it. Otherwise, Linux will try to get some stats in software (sampling value of %pc in an interrupt, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

The [ARM Profiler User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0414e/index.html) says an [instruction trace](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0414e/RP_data_rtsm_Enabling_and_disabling_program_trace_collection.html) can be created when run in a [Real-Time System Model](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0414e/chapter_3.html) 
and can display executed instructions counts in The Code and Replay Views [disassembly panel](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0414e/RP_code_view_The_disassembly_view.html).