# ARM performance counters vs linux clock_gettime

Tags: linux, arm, performancecounter, gettime, time-measurement

I am using a Zynq chip on a development board ( ZC702 ) ,
which has a dual cortex-A9 MPCore at 667MHz and comes with a Linux kernel 3.3
I wanted to compare the execution time of a program so first a used
clock_gettime and then used the counters provided by the co-processor
of ARM. The counter increment every one processor cycle. 
( based on this [question of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247373/how-to-measure-program-execution-time-in-arm-cortex-a8-processor) and [this](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3291))

I compile the program with -O0 flag ( since I don't want any reordering or optimization done)

The time  I measure with the performance counters is 
583833498 ( cycles ) / 666.666687 MHz = **875750.221** (microseconds)

While using clock_gettime() ( either REALTIME or MONOTONIC or MONOTONIC_RAW )
the time measured is : 
**731627.126** ( microseconds)
which is **150000** microseconds less..

Can anybody explain me why is this happening?
Why is there a difference? The processor does not clock-scale , how is it possible to 
get less execution time measured by clock_gettime ? I have a sample code below:

---

```c
#define RUNS 50000000
#define BENCHMARK(val) \
__asm__  __volatile__("mov r4, %1\n\t" \
                 "mov r5, #0\n\t" \
                 "1:\n\t"\
                 "add r5,r5,r4\n\t"\
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "mov r4 ,r4  \n\t" \
                 "sub r4,r4,#1\n\t" \
                 "cmp r4, #0\n\t" \
                 "bne 1b\n\t" \
                 "mov %0 ,r5  \n\t" \
                 :"=r" (val) \
                 : "r" (RUNS) \
                 : "r4","r5" \
        );
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&start);
__asm__ __volatile__ ("MRC p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0\t\n": "=r"(start_cycles));
for(index=0;index<5;index++)
{
    BENCHMARK(i);
}
__asm__ __volatile__ ("MRC p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0\t\n": "=r"(end_cycles));
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&stop);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. I upgraded the platform from a linux kernel 3.3.0 to 3.5 and the value is similar to that of the performance counters. Apparently the frequency of the clock counter in 3.3.0 is assumed higher that what it is ( around 400 MHz ) instead of half of the CPU frequency. Probably a porting error in the old version.

Comment: @auselen It was not my fault for the clock issue, I just used the BSP that came with the board.I assumed that it would be working.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX clocks operate within certain precision, which you can get with `clock_getres`.  Check if that 150,000us difference is inside or outside the error margin.

In any case, it shouldn't matter, you should repeat you benchmark many times, not 5, but 1000 or more. You can then get the timing of a single benchmark run like

`((end + e1) - (start + e0)) / 1000`, or

`(end - start) / 1000 + (e1 - e0) / 1000`.

If `e1` and `e0` are the error terms, which are bound by a small constant, your maximum measurement error will be `abs (e1 - e0) / 1000`, which will be negligible as the number of loops increase.

Comment: I do not need to run the program more times since benchmark is already a loop. I updated the code I pasted above.
And as mentioned to @auselen the getres is 1nsec