# Linux perf stat tool returns zero instructions count. What am I missing here?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, galaxy, perf

I am trying to get some basic performance data on my new Galaxy S4 phone. I've already compiled a custom kernel and managed to flash it onto the device using Odin. These are the kernel modules related to perf tool that I have enabled:

```
CONFIG_HAVE_PERF_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_PERF_USE_VMALLOC=y
CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_PERF_COUNTERS=y
```

I've also cross-compiled the perf tool. The problem is that when I run the following command:

```
perf stat ls
```

The output does not seem to be quite right:

```
Performance counter stats for 'ls':
10887392 cycles    # 0.000 Ghz
       0 instructions # 0.00 insns per cycle
0.012448321 seconds time elapsed
```

I've set the cpu policies to 'userspace' and did:

```
cpufreq-set -f 1600000
```

in order to make sure that all the cores are always working at max frequency.

I would appreciate any help.

Here are links to similar cases without a solution:
http://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-kernel/2012-December/002611.html
http://forums.arm.com/index.php?/topic/15020-pmu-in-cortex-a8-omap-3530-what-am-i-doing-wrong/

Relevant stackoverflow topic:
[How to measure program execution time in ARM Cortex-A8 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247373/how-to-measure-program-execution-time-in-arm-cortex-a8-processor)

Comment: What is your Galaxy S4 model (GT-I900x)?

Comment: Side question: how can I enable those CONFIG_ kernel modules?

Answer (score 2):

Can you see other HW events like "CPU cycles" or "cache misses"?

```
perf stat -e cache-misses,cycles ls
```

You might want to set CONFIG_HW_PERF_EVENTS as well.

Comment: I also think CONFIG_HW_EVENTS may be missing. To check first.