# MCR and MRC does not exist on AARCH64?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm64

I am trying to compile "mrc" and "mcr" instruction on AARCH64 based on Board but I am seeing below error message

```
   tmp/ccqOHmrK.s: Assembler messages:
  /tmp/ccqOHmrK.s:43: Error: unknown mnemonic `mrc' -- `mrc p15,0,x0,c14,c3,1'
  /tmp/ccqOHmrK.s:53: Error: unknown mnemonic `mrc' -- `mrc p15,0,x2,c14,c3,0'
```

I tried looking into the kernel source /arch/arm64 but no where mcr&&mrc has been used without emulation.

Is it some syntax issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should replace these with the appropriate `msr` instructions.
For example, [arch/arm/include/asm/arch_timer.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/arch_timer.h?id=082471a8efe1a91d4e44abec202d9e3067dcec91#n34) has:

```
case ARCH_TIMER_REG_CTRL:
    asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c14, c3, 1" : : "r" (val));
```

The counterpart in [arch/arm64/include/asm/arch_timer.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/include/asm/arch_timer.h?id=082471a8efe1a91d4e44abec202d9e3067dcec91#n40) has:

```
case ARCH_TIMER_REG_CTRL:
    asm volatile("msr cntv_ctl_el0,  %0" : : "r" (val));
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you. But may I know from you, is MCR/MRC  deprecated in ARMv8 ?

Comment: They certainly aren't listed in the instruction set documentation and the assembler doesn't know them either, so I'd say they don't exist.

Comment: Links are not valid.

Comment: Lucky I copied the code into the answer. The links are just for source reference. Anyway, updated them but no telling how long they stay stable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`MCR` and `MRC` don't exist in ARMv8.

In ARMv7-A, system registers were typically accessed through coprocessor 15 (CP15) operations and accessed using `MCR` and `MRC`. However, AArch64 does not include support for coprocessors.

In AArch64, system configuration is controlled through system registers, and accessed using `MSR` and `MRS` instructions.

If you want to access a system register, you could refer to Arm Architecture Reference Manual. For example, `PMSELR_EL0` in D13.4.15.
[image]