# ::"r" vs :"=r" assembly clarification

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm trying to understand the syntax of writing in assembly to first write the code correctly and second efficiently. 
in this example it shows the example using `"=r"`

```
asm volatile ("MRS %0, PMUSERENR_EL0\n": "=r"(value));
```

this reads the value of the register and stores it in the value variable. The other example uses `::"r"`

```
asm volatile ("MSR PMUSERENR_EL0, %0\n":: "r"(value));
```

This writes the value variable to the PMUSERENR_ELO register. Here is another example of it:[How to measure program execution time in ARM Cortex-A8 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247373/how-to-measure-program-execution-time-in-arm-cortex-a8-processor/3250835#3250835).

When I attempt to compile a simple test code with the two above commands i get the error: `:9:2: error: output operand constraint lacks '='` If I add the "=" and remove one ":" it will compile but when I test it, it simply says `Illegal instruction`

If someone could please explain the difference that would be helpful numerous assembly tutorials show the same format but no explanation. Its on a 64 bit arm platform if that offers any insight. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure used two colons? (`::`)

Comment: See [this collection of links to GNU C inline asm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm/34522750#34522750), including links to [the official gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) that explain input vs. output constraints.

Comment: this is not assembly this is inline assembly specific to one compiler, basically this is a C/C++ question not an assembly question.

Comment: Perhaps it's being confused with the :: operator? It might be worth trying to add a space between the colons (`: :`). Just a thought.

Comment: whats the difference between the :: operator and the : operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer in the book: [Professional Assembly Language: Extended ASM](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bl0_hWV20TAC&pg=PA370&lpg=PA370&dq=two+colon+%22::%22+in+assembly+language&source=bl&ots=Ha8EkNUJee&sig=p6v6iPOCYjBJdmBBVx2ZdxoRT2I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8xcOElYnMAhVQ_WMKHR-JC7IQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=two%20colon%20%22%3A%3A%22%20in%20assembly%20language&f=false)

> If no output values are associated with the assembly code, the section
> must be blank, but two colons must still separate the assembly code
> from the input operands.

The why is because that's the standard. One colon for outputs and two for inputs.

Comment: `asm("template" : outputs : inputs : clobbers)`.  It's "two colons" for input only if you don't have any outputs in the same asm statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have rightly pointed to the explanation, but wrongly formatted the statement "One colon for outputs and two for inputs"

In the extend version of asm format as shown below

`asm("assembly code" : outputs : inputs : clobbers)`

if you do not have outputs, you should still include the Colon, which translates as follows

`asm("assembly code"::inputs:clobbers)`

If you do not have clobbers (changed registers) you can omit the last Colon, which translates as
`asm("assembly code":outputs:inputs)`